# how to check which image view i have added in xml programmatically?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I added some imageviews in `xml` layout. Now programmatically i need to check which `imageView` i have added from the `xml` file  and if same image then  on click of that image i need to replace new image and visa versa.

Is the way i implemented it good or can I find a better solution for this?

This is my code so far:

```
 holder.bankTickImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.bankTickImg.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_untick))) {
                    holder.bankTickImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_tick);
                }else{
                    holder.bankTickImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_untick);
                }
            }

        });
```

**Imageview Code**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/defaultBankTick"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/TwentyFour"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/TwentyFour"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/FiftyFive"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Thirty"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/FiftyFive"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_untick" />
```

Comment: post your xml code  and add more code snippets

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/defaultBankTick"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TwentyFour"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TwentyFour"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/FiftyFive"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Thirty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/FiftyFive"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_untick" />

Comment: layout xml code

Comment: image is placed in recycler view

Comment: On click not working

Comment: check with my updated ans

Comment: did you try with my ans?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question.

Why don't you use a integer/boolean variable to save the state. **eg.**

lets say, you start with

```
int clicked = 0;
```

then in on click check if its value it **0** then treat it as fresh and change the value to **1**.

and if the value is already **1** then treat it as it clicked 2nd time and change it to **0** .

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check `imageView` which you added

```
    holder.bankTickImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_untick); //default image , you can also set in xml code
    holder.bankTickImg.setId(0);//you also do with string setTag();

  holder.bankTickImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int istick=holder.bankTickImg.getId();
            if (istick==1)
            {
                holder.bankTickImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_tick);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.bankTickImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_untick);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: how to compare whether its frist tag or second tag on click of image

Comment: on image click ,if apple image shown frist then checking the id i need to set other image and vice versa